# Size of textboxes and combo boxes

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, devexpress-wpf

I am working with a wpf app.  I designed my GUI using the controls and xaml.  All that was well until I installed Devexpress on my computer.  Now all my buttons, textboxes, and comboboxes have been resized. I am now having trouble letting my text show properly within these controls.  For example, the height of my textboxes has to be over 36 for my text to show in them. Is there a fix to this? I have placed a screenshot of my window for reference. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The default theme (DXStyle) is applied to all controls, that is the issue reason.
So to fix it you have to reset the [ThemeManager.ThemeName](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfCoreThemeManager_ThemeNametopic) attached property to None:

```
<UserControl / Panel / ContentControl / ItemsControl etc.
        . . .
        xmlns:dx="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core"
        dx:ThemeManager.ThemeName="None">
```